# Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with A table type

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

When i am trying to send parameters to sql-server i am sending a list which will get binded with a table type parameter in SQL server. i am adding parameter to the parameter list like this:

```cs
SqlParameter para6 = new SqlParameter();
para6.ParameterName = "ObjectAttrList";
para6.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
para6.Value = null;
para6.IsNullable = true;
if (attrList != null && attrList.Count > 0)
{
    para6.Value = attrList;
}
para6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
sqlParameters[5] = para6;
```

and this is the  sql procedure with which ill be inserting data:

```
@ObjectAttrList  [ObjectStore].[ObjectStoreAttributes] READONLY )
```

while doing this i am getting an error like:"Operand type clash: NULL is incompatible with ObjectStoreAttributes"
i searched a lot about this and tried solutions accordingly. but none of them seems to work. any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your intended value of ObjectStoreAttributes?

Answer (score 0):

in your 4th line instead of using

> para6.Value = null;

use

> para6.Value = (object)DBNull.Value;